# Python nested loop triangle

Tags: python, python-3.x

The output I am trying to achieve is :

```
##
# #
#  #
#   #
#    #
#     #
```

The code I have is :

```
NUM_STEPS = 6

for r in range(NUM_STEPS):
   for c in range(r):
      print(' ', end='')
   print('#','\t')
   print('#')
```

Its close, but not quite the output I am trying to achieve. Any help or suggestions are most appreciated.

Comment: Look into the format function

Comment: If you love one-liners: `print(*((' '*x).join('##') for x in range(6)), sep='\n')`

Answer (score 4):

The main thing is you should use '+' (or concat) to build up a string before printing it.
You can eliminate the inner loop by using '*' to make `r` spaces, which cleans things up a lot.

```
NUM_STEPS = 6
for r in range(NUM_STEPS):
    print("#" + (' ' * r) + "#")
```

Comment: Yes, the `*` operator for strings really is handy :)

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work when I tried it:

```
for r in range(NUM_STEPS):
    print("#", end = "")
    for c in range(r):
        print(" ", end = "")
    print("#")
```

I hope it helps.